# Non-model join on Propel

Tags: php, propel

How to write this on Propel? Schema:

```
obj
--
id
object_id

foo
--
id
```

SQL:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM
    foo f INNER JOIN obj o ON f.id=o.object_id
ORDER BY
    o.id
;
```

PHP:

```
$join = new \Join();
$join->addExplicitCondition(
    'foo', 'id', 'f',
    'obj', 'object_id', 'o',
    \Join::EQUAL
);

$join->setJoinType(\Criteria::INNER_JOIN);

$objectsQuery = FooQuery::create()
    ->setModelAlias('f', true)
    ->addJoinObject($join, 'o')
    ->addAscendingOrderByColumn('o.id') // error here
    ;
```

Outputs:

```
Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined table: o
```

I'm using Propel 1.7. And note that I dont have model relation between "obj" and "foo" (its supposed to be polymorphic relation). And I'd rather avoid writing custom SQL. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need the 2nd parameter to `addJoinObject`?  Try just `->addJoinObject($join)`.

Comment: Tried that... nothing changes.

Comment: What if you did `->addAscendingOrderByColumn('obj.id')`?

Comment: `->addAscendingOrderByColumn('obj.id')` did not help. But `->addAlias($join->getRightTableAlias(), $join->getRightTableName())` did.

Comment: Cool!  You got it working! :-)  I assumed `addExplicitCondition` would've taken care of the aliases.  Guess you still needed to set them :)

Comment: Posted too early :) Forgot that ENTER sends comment :P What did help, was `->addAlias($join->getRightTableAlias(), $join->getRightTableName())`. So, final query is: `$objectsQuery = FooQuery::create()->setModelAlias('f', true)->addJoinObject($join, 'o')->addAlias($join->getRightTableAlias(), $join->getRightTableName())->addAscendingOrderByColumn('o.id');`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding JoinObject does not add proper aliases, so I have to add them myself. This works:

```
$objectsQuery = FooQuery::create()
   ->setModelAlias('f', true)
   ->addJoinObject($join, 'o') // 'o' here makes no difference, actually
   ->addAlias($join->getRightTableAlias(), $join->getRightTableName())
   ->addAscendingOrderByColumn('o.id');
```